# Definitions of the KML folders for the Sentinel 2 data acquisition plans

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth, sentinel-2, esa

I'm trying to plan a HABs study and part of that requires pairing in-situ data with sentinel 2A and 2B imagery.  I was trying to look at the acquisition plan to get future dates.  I downloaded the KML from:

https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/acquisition-plans

When I open it in Google Earth I see a set of folders.  I can't find the definitions of "NOBs", "VIC", "Dark-o" and "Sun".  I've read through all the tabs on the ESA sentinel website and the handbook and can't find these terms nor can I when I google these terms with Sentinel 2.

[image: KML for the data acquisition plan]

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?  I'm very new to Sentinel data.